# TSQL - An object or column name is missing or empty

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a script that moves the tempDB-Log if it's on the wrong partition (I was asked to).

I've tried every damn possible combination of " and ' plus saving the ALTER DATABASE into a variable and running afterwards.

This script is not finished after this. Database restart and more functionality plus optimization comes afterwards (that's my first tsql script).

```
DECLARE @NAME nvarchar(100),

SELECT @NAME = name 
FROM master.sys.master_files 
WHERE (name = 'templog' OR name LIKE '%TempDB_log') 
  AND physical_name NOT LIKE 'G%';

ALTER DATABASE tempdb 
MODIFY FILE (name = '@NAME', filename = ''G:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.TEST\MSSQL\Data\'@NAME'.ldf'');
GO
```

That's how it should look for `templog.ldf`:

```
ALTER DATABASE tempdb 
MODIFY FILE (name=templog, filename='G:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.TEST\MSSQL\Data\templog.ldf');
```

Comment: `'@NAME'`? Are you sure that's how you use variables in a tsql string literal? shouldn't it be `filename='G:\....' + @name + '.ldf'`?

Comment: Try removing the qutoes around `@Name` in your `ALTER DATABASE` statement.  Also, why do you have 2 quotes around your filename?  Are you trying to create some dynamic SQL to move your log files?

Comment: that's just the version I was currently testing. Error was always along the lines of: wrong syntax at @NAME ... trying all suggestions out now

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @NAME nvarchar(100);

SELECT @NAME = name 
FROM master.sys.master_files 
WHERE (name = 'templog' OR name LIKE '%TempDB_log') 
  AND physical_name NOT LIKE 'G%';

DECLARE @alterSql VARCHAR(MAX) = 
    'ALTER DATABASE tempdb '
    + 'MODIFY FILE (name = ' 
    + @NAME 
    + ', filename = ''G:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.TEST\MSSQL\Data\'
    + @NAME 
    + '.ldf'');'

EXEC (@alterSql)
```

It produces this string:

```
ALTER DATABASE tempdb 
MODIFY FILE 
(
    name = templog, 
    filename = 'G:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.TEST\MSSQL\Data\templog.ldf'
);
```

Comment: Op just copy pasted your answer instead of accepting yours.

Comment: I did use his answer. still got error/no result and did some other things as well.

Comment: I guess an acknowledgement of someone trying to help you is an effort too great to bear.